# A word/phrase to mean 'Beauty is in the eye of the beholder' without sounding old school/erudite/pretentious

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

To tell someone you don't agree with their view on what is good looking in a light-hearted way.

For instance, you visit a very skilled tattoo artist but his view on what looks good is not the same as you. What is a better way to say 'beauty is in the eye of the beholder' or 'beauty is subjective'?

> I trust your professionalism and skill but  *fill_in_the_blank_here*.

What about using *aesthetic view*?

> I trust your professionalism and skill but we don't share the same
>   aesthetic view?

I'm thinking if *aesthetic eyes* is appropriate?

> I trust your professionalism and skill but not so on your *aesthetic eyes*

Comment: The phrase you mention, 'beauty is in the eye of the beholder', is a good one. It's well-known and still used. Why do you think it's old-school, erudite or pretentious?

Comment: @RosieF It sounds cliché.

Answer (score 1):

To each their own

Whatever floats your boat

Sure, whatever you like

I would just say we don't share the same aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be more about putting something appropriate into place in the example sentence than, strictly speaking, an alternative to *beauty is in the eye of the beholder*. (Because I don't think *that* phrase fits into the example sentence.)

I would say this:

> I trust your professionalism and skill, but **I'm afraid we have different tastes.**

In this case, [*taste*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taste) is using the following senses:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **5** : individual preference : INCLINATION
>   **6 a** : critical judgment, discernment, or appreciation
>   **6 b** : manner or aesthetic quality indicative of such discernment or appreciation

---

Note that purely as an alternative to *beauty is the eye of the beholder*, I like *people see what they want to see*. However, as I said, neither of these expressions, or others like them, would work with the example sentence.

Comment: I agree... "That's not really my taste," is probably the most tactful way to disagree with someone else's aesthetic *sensibilities* (- the term we used in art school).